# Grails + Spring Security one field login

Tags: security, spring, authentication, grails

Is it possible, using spring security plugin 0.5.3 with Grails 1.2.1, to authenticate a user using only one field? I mean, for example, making j_username and j_password fields in the authentication form equal previous to the authentication. I read it was possible to define j_username field in Config.groovy with acegi plugin, in older versions of the plugin. Now it uses SecurityConfig.groovy but the possibility of defining the field exists no more.

Any ideas??

Thanks a lot,

Miguel

Comment: You're creating an application where if you just know the login name of a user, it will log you in with that user?

Comment: correct... the user is supplied an 'identity code' via ordinary mail, and it's supposed to be unique. I want to use this code as single field for authentication with spring security and grails... is it possible?

Comment: One solution to me is using the same value for username and password in the database and make the user enter the same code two times, but I'd want to know if it's possible doing it the other way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the j_password field hidden and then when you render the login page you can populate the hidden field with a hard coded password that is common to all users.

```
<g:hiddenField value="${passwordVal}" name='j_password' id='j_password' />
```

Then when you login the hidden field is submitted.

Its not perfect, but should work for your needs.

Comment: Yeah, it fits my needs; however, I think I'll end using two fields with the same code, like a confirmation. Thanks a lot!